# Custom Formatting within a Cell in ObjectListView in C#

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I'm just about to begin a new project where I'm hoping to make use of the ObjectListView. I've been doing a bunch of reading through this forum and there is one thing I haven't quite been able to figure out if it is possible with the ObjectListView (or the FastObjectListView).

In this project, I'm hoping to be able to do some custom formatting of text within a cell, where only certain words or sections of the string contents are bolded, or being able to change the .

An example use case: if I have a cell that contains the following string, "Hello my Name is Bob." I'm hoping to setup so only the word "my" is bolded and the word "is" is in a different colour (for example have it in red).

I have been looking at the ObjectListView decorations and am thinking that that would be one route, but I wasn't sure if there was some other control within the ObjectListView that would natively allow me to do this type of formatting. Something that I could include in the FormatCell callback? Or is it only possible to apply formatting to the entire string contents of the cell?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a custom renderer to achieve what you want. You can find a [good example over here](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/ownerDraw.html#baserenderer-a-renderer-s-utility-belt).

```
public class GradientRenderer : BaseRenderer
{
    public override void Render(Graphics g, Rectangle r) {
        using (LinearGradientBrush gradient = new LinearGradientBrush(r, Color.Gold, Color.Fuchsia, 0.0)) {
            g.FillRectangle(gradient, r);
        }
        StringFormat fmt = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoWrap);
        fmt.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        fmt.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter;
        switch (this.Column.TextAlign) {
            case HorizontalAlignment.Center: fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center; break;
            case HorizontalAlignment.Left: fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near; break;
            case HorizontalAlignment.Right: fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far; break;
        }
        g.DrawString(this.GetText(), this.Font, this.TextBrush, r, fmt);
    }
}
```

You can assign a renderer to a cell using

```
myOlvColumn.Renderer = new GradientRenderer();
```

You could try to render/draw/overlay a RichTextBox into the cell. That would making showing individually formatted text easier. Not sure if that is possible.

Comment: Thank you @Rev1.0 I'll give a shot at building a Renderer.